# setting value on a div not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, aura-iteration

I cant set value on div during aura iteration, the reason why I need to set it on a div cause the div is writable contentEditable = true;I want to display value there so it can be edit it.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.EmpolyeeList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
   <div aura:id="empolyeeDes" class="setText" value="{!item.EmpolyeeDescription__c}" >
   </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

and controller

```
    var textAreaComponentOne = component.find('empolyeeDes');
    var textAreaElementOne   = textAreaComponentOne.getElement();
    textAreaElementOne.contentEditable = true;
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and show a little more of your code?  Where is textAreaElementOne in your markup?  Where is EmpolyeeList set in your controller?

Comment: Why would you even think `<div value="...">` would be useful here? If you want in input, you need some sort of input element. Besides which, you set the content of a `div` using content inside of it, not the `value` attribute.

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld textAreaElementOne is the div <div aura:id="empolyeeDes" im using the id empolyeeDes and i assigned to var textAreaComponentOne as u see in the code. I'm using EmpolyeeList to just display the data, not doing anything else with it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the the div is my input that is why im setting it to contentEditable = true;... the value is coming form the EmpolyeeList, need to be edit inside the div. why im choosing a div as input because, im doing a input table and a writable div looks better in the table.

Comment: @AdrianLarson -- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld That doesn't disprove my point at all. The example uses a text node, there is no `value` attribute on the `<p>` tag.

Comment: @AdrianLarson your right I CAN'T set any value attribute on html tags, What i did is loop through them and setting it using .innerHTML is kinda dirty way but that is the only way I have right now

Answer (score 1):

You can't add value attribute to a `<div>`. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

You can however value attribute on input tags like the code below. You will no longer need to add contentEditable = true to that element since input is editable by nature.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.EmpolyeeList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
   <input aura:id="empolyeeDes" class="setText" value="{!item.EmpolyeeDescription__c}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

or you can use `lightning:input`:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.EmpolyeeList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
       <lightning:input aura:id="empolyeeDes" class="setText" value="{!item.EmpolyeeDescription__c}" />
</aura:iteration>
```